# Where can I validate my music compositions?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, music

After somebody creates his/her own new song, where does (s)he need to *register/verify* to be sure it's not a plagiarism?

I'm curious how these things work–who has the power to say a song is a plagiarism of another song or not? Is there any tool to verify this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool (other than, say, Shazam)...you would typically find out when another artist notifies you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone in a country without strong laws against libel can accuse you of plagiarism. If I hear your song on the radio, I'm free to say "it sounds just like xyz written by abc in 1968". But that doesn't mean anything.

If Mr. ABC himself thinks "it just sounds like xyz that I wrote in 1968", then he can accuse you of copyright infringement. And take you to court. And a judge or a jury, supported by expert witnesses, would make the decision whether you copied the song or not.